# Bash Script to batch-convert IP Addresses to CIDR?

Tags: bash, batch-file, ip, iptables

Ok, here's the problem.

I have a plaintext list of IP addresses that I'm blocking on my servers, growing more and more unwieldy every day (added 3000+ entries today alone).

It's already been sorted for duplicates so that's not a problem. What I'd like to do is write a script to go through it and consolidate the entries a bit better for mass blocking.

For example, take this:

```
2.132.35.104
2.132.79.240
2.132.99.87
2.132.236.34
2.132.245.30
```

And turn it into this:

```
2.132.0.0/16
```

Any suggestions on how to code that in a bash script?

UPDATE: I've worked out part-way how to do what I'm needing. Converting it to /24 is easy, as follows:

```
cat /usr/local/blocks/blocks.txt | while read line; do
    oc1=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 1`
    oc2=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 2`
    oc3=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 3`
    oc4=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 4`
    echo "$oc1.$oc2.$oc3.0/24" >> twentyfour.srt
done

sort -u twentyfour.srt > twentyfour.txt
rm -f twentyfour.srt
ori=`cat /usr/local/blocks/blocks.txt | wc -l`
new=`cat twentyfour.txt | wc -l`
echo "$ori"
echo "$new"
```

That reduced it down from 4,452 entries to 4,148 entries.

Instead of having:

```
109.86.9.93
109.86.26.77
109.86.55.225
109.86.70.224
109.86.87.199
109.86.89.202
109.86.95.248
109.86.100.19
109.86.110.43
109.86.145.216
109.86.152.86
109.86.155.238
109.86.156.54
109.86.187.91
109.86.228.86
109.86.234.51
109.86.239.61
```

I now have:

```
109.86.100.0/24
109.86.110.0/24
109.86.145.0/24
109.86.152.0/24
109.86.155.0/24
109.86.156.0/24
109.86.187.0/24
109.86.228.0/24
109.86.234.0/24
109.86.239.0/24
109.86.26.0/24
109.86.55.0/24
109.86.70.0/24
109.86.87.0/24
109.86.89.0/24
109.86.9.0/24
109.86.95.0/24
```

All well and good. BUT, there's 17 entries from the 109.86.*.* area. In a case where the first 2 octets match more than say 5 entries on /24, I'd like to reduce that to /16.

That's where I'm stuck.

UPDATE 2:

For Steve: [Here's the block list for today.](http://pastebin.com/0UeA9gxM) And here's the [result so far.](http://pastebin.com/7viyFSWp) Apparently it's not removing the near-duplicate entries from twentyfour that are in sixteen.

Comment: This very much depends on how specific you want your subnets to be, relative to the IPs that are blocked. Do you always want to block entire `/16`s for only a few hosts? Do you want your consolidation to be mathematically exact to the list of individual hosts? Somewhere in between?

Comment: That's a very good question! Ideally, if there's more than x entries from a given host, /16 would be better than say /24, wouldn't it? I don't want to block the entire world, just the malicious IPs, in as few entries as possible. So going by my above example, 2.132.0.0/16 would be good since there's about 20 IPs from that range in the file. But if it's just 2-3 entries, /24 would be plenty.

Comment: Based on my past experience as a managed firewall engineer, I wouldn't recommend automatically blocking something as large as a `/16`, but that's an opinion based on working with customers' networks. Since these are your own servers, however, go with what you think is right. You could also automate some `whois` lookups to be more comfortable in blocking such large ranges.

Comment: You've got me thinking now that /24 would probably be the best way to go, at least for now. But that still leaves me with the problem of batch-convewrting this list.

Comment: I assume that each lists only contains addresses from one subnet, and you need to figure out what the size of that subnet is?

Comment: Actually, no. The list (now at 4,431 entries) is just 1 IP per line of everyone I'm blocking. I have a script in place that reads the list and adds each line to an iptables BLOCK chain, as well as a script that monitors various logs to gather the IP addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wish I could tell you this is a simple filter. However, all of the 2.0.0.0/8 network is registered to RIPE NCC. There's just way too many different ranges of blocked IP addresses, its easier to just narrow down the scope of visitors you do want versus what you don't want.

You could also use various tools you can use to block attacks automatically.

**Map to identify which is which. https://www.iana.org/numbers**
Here's a script I just made for you. Then you can create the major block lists for each of the primary registries. Afrinic, Lacnic, Apnic, Ripe, and Arin.
**create_tables_by_registry.sh**

Just run this script... Then run the following registry.sh files. (E.g; ripe.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Steve Kline
# Date: 03-04-2014
# Designed and tested to run on properly on CentOS 6.5
#Grab Updated IANA Address Space Assignments only if Newer Version
    wget -N https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.txt
assigned=ipv4-address-space.txt
arrayregistry=( afrinic apnic arin lacnic ripe )
for registry in "${arrayregistry[@]}"
do
#Clean up the ipv4-address-space.txt file and keep useable IPs
grep "$registry" $assigned | sed 's/\/8/\.0\.0\.0\/8/g'| colrm 15 > $registry-tmp1.txt
ip=($(cat $registry-tmp1.txt))
echo "#!/bin/bash" > $registry.sh
for ip in "${ip[@]}"
    do
    echo $ip | sed -e 's/"   "//g'  > $registry-tmp2.txt
    #INSERT OR MODIFY YOUR COMPATIBLE FIREWALL RULES HERE
    #This section creates the country to block.
    echo "iptables -A INPUT -s $ip -j DROP" >> $registry.sh
    chmod +x $registry.sh
done
    rm $registry-tmp1.txt -f
    rm $registry-tmp2.txt -f
done
```

Ok! Well I'm back, a little insane here and a little nutty there... I think I helped figure this out for you. I'm sure you can piece together a modification to better fit your needs.

```
#MODIFY FOR YOUR LIST OF IP ADDRESSES
BADIPS=block.ip
twentyfour=./twentyfour.ips #temp file for all IPs converted to twentyfour net ids
sixteen=./sixteen.ips   #temp file for sixteen bit
twentyfourlst1=./twentyfour1.txt    #temp file for 24 bit IDs
twentyfourlst2=./twentyfour2.txt    #temp file for 24 bit IDs filtered by 16 bit IDs that match
sixteenlst=./sixteen.txt    #temp file for parsed sixteenbit
#MODIFY FOR YOUR OUTPUT OF CIDR ADDRESSES
finalfile=./blockips.list   #Final file post-merge

cat $BADIPS | while read line; do
oc1=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 1`
oc2=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 2`
oc3=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 3`
oc4=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 4`
echo "$oc1.$oc2.$oc3.0/24" >> $twentyfour
echo "$oc1.$oc2.0.0/16" >> $sixteen
done
awk '{i=1;while(i <= NF){a[$(i++)]++}}END{for(i in a){if(a[i]>4){print i,a[i]}}}' $sixteen | sed 's/ [0-9]\| [0-9][0-9]\| [0-9][0-9][0-9]//g' > $sixteenlst
sort -u $twentyfour > twentyfour.txt
# THIS FINDS NEAR DUPLICATES MATCHING FIRST TWO OCTETS
cat $sixteenlst | while read line; do
   oc1=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 1`
   oc2=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 2`
   oc3=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 3`
   oc4=`echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 4`
   grep "\b$oc1.$oc2\b" twentyfour.txt >> duplicates.txt    
done
#THIS REMOVES THE NEAR DUPLICATES FROM THE TWENTYFOUR FILE
fgrep -vw -f duplicates.txt twentyfour.txt > twentyfourfinal.txt
#THIS MERGES BOTH RESULTS
cat twentyfourfinal.txt $sixteenlst > $finalfile
sort -u $finalfile
ori=`cat $BADIPS | wc -l`
new=`cat $finalfile | wc -l`
echo "$ori"
echo "$new"
#LAST MIN CLEANUP
rm -f $twentyfour $twentyfourlst $sixteen $sixteenlst duplicates.txt twentyfourfinal.txt
```

Going Back to fix: I noted a problem... Originally unsuccessful.
`grep "$oc1.$oc1" twentyfour.txt > duplicates.txt

> For Example: The old script had bad results with this test IP range... the updated version now above... Does exactly as its intended. match the octet exactly.. and not a similar.

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.50
192.168.5.23
192.168.14.10
192.168.10.5
192.168.24.25
192.165.20.10
10.192.168.30
5.76.10.20
5.76.20.30
5.76.250.10
5.76.34.10
5.76.50.30
95.76.30.1    - Old script matched this to 5.76
20.20.5.5
20.20.10.10
20.20.16.50
20.20.205.20
20.20.60.20
205.20.16.20 - not a  problem
20.205.150.150 - Old script matched this to 20.20
220.20.16.0 - Also failed without adding -w parameter to the last grep to only match exact strings.
```

Comment: Thank you for writing that script, I'll save a copy of it! But in all honesty, I don't care where the attacks are from. If more than x attacks come from a specific block, I want to stop that block completely. 1-2 attacks from xxx.yyy.zzz.* means block just that IP. 4-5 attacks from xxx.yyy.*.* means block /24. And anything higher than that, /16 just to be safe.

Comment: It's mostly working, but quite a few entries are showing up like: 222.186.0.0/164
37.212.0.0/165
95.132.0.0/164
37.52.0.0/161
37.215.0.0/165
93.171.0.0/164

Comment: Almost there, but now it's throwing some errors: `cat: ./block.ip: No such file or directory
cat: ./blockip.list: No such file or directory
0
0`

Comment: Well, that fixed the errors, but the /16 isn't working very well. For example, I have a bunch of entries that start with 176.36. which should change to 176.36.0.0/16 but it's just dropping the last octet and adding 0/24. Fantastic progress so far though.

Comment: I see what it's doing now, after a final sort! [Here's the result!](http://pastebin.com/7viyFSWp)

Comment: Copy the new update: Change the BADIPs variable to your file and the finalfile variable to your desired output file. That's all it.

Comment: That cut the list down from 4,677 entries to 2,943! I think that's a success! Thanks!

Comment: Due to new discover, I updated the script. Please do so on your own and see the example I gave. It still wasn't working properly when we called it good last night.